# C# Regex filter problems

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

At this moment in time, i posted something earlier asking about the same type of question regarding `Regex`. It has given me headaches, i have looked up loads of documentation of how to use regex but i still could not put my finger on it. I wouldn't want to waste another 6 hours looking to filter simple (i think) expressions.

So basically what i want to do is filter all filetypes with  the endings of HTML extensions (the '*' stars are from a Winforms Tabcontrol signifying that the file has been modified. I also need them in `IgnoreCase`:

```
.html, .htm, .shtml, .shtm, .xhtml
.html*, .htm*, .shtml*, .shtm*, .xhtml*
```

Also filtering some CSS files:

```
.css
.css*
```

And some SQL Files:

```
.sql, .ddl, .dml
.sql*, .ddl*, .dml*
```

My previous question got an answer to filtering Python files:

```
.py, .py, .pyi, .pyx, .pyw
Expression would be: \.py[3ixw]?\*?$
```

But when i tried to learn from the expression above i would always end up with opening a `.xhtml` only, the rest are not valid.

For the HTML expression, i currently have this: `\.html|.html|.shtml|.shtm|.xhtml\*?$` with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. But the output will only allow `.xhtml` case sensitive or insensitive. .html files, .htm and the rest did not match. I would really appreciate an explanation to each of the expressions you provide (so i don't have to ask the same question ever again).

Thank you.

Comment: `*` in wildcards stands for any 0 or more chars. You probably want `(?i)\.[xs]?htm\w*$`, `(?i)\.css\w*$` and `(?i)\.py\w*$` / `(?i)\.py[3ixw]?$`. Note you still do not escape all `.`s.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So the expression i had above, `\.html|.html|.shtml|.shtm|.xhtml\*?$` wouldn't work because everything else than `.xhtml` had the `.` escaped?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. See [what your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/HPEo4j/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for providing that. Last question actually, i'm taking a guess here with the filters of `SQL files` i mentioned above. I tried out this expression: `\.[a-zA-Z]+$`. Would that be a correct way to implement? Or is there another efficient way? Thanks again.

Comment: SQLite3 files can have `.sq3` extension, then, you need to add digits to the regex, `\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, yes thank you. Forgot about that! Thank you so much for helping me. I hope i won't spend another 6 hours again for this now that i've learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases you may start with a simple regex that can be simplified step by step down to a good regex expression:

In C# this would basically, with IgnoreCase, be

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex("PATTERN", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Now the pattern: The most easy one is simply concatenating all valid results with OR + escaping (if possible):

```
\.html|\.htm|\.shtml|\.shtm|\.xhtml|\.html*|\.htm*|\.shtml*|\.shtm*|\.xhtml*
```

With `.html*` you mean `.html` + anything, which is written as `.*`(Any character, 0-infinite times) in regex.

```
\.html|\.htm|\.shtml|\.shtm|\.xhtml|\.html.*|\.htm.*|\.shtml.*|\.shtm.*|\.xhtml.*
```

Then, you may take all repeating patterns and group them together. All file endings start with a dot and may have an optional end and `ending.*` always contains `ending`:

```
\.(html|htm|shtml|shtm|xhtml).*
```

Then, I see `htm` pretty often, so I try to extract that. Taking all possible characters before and after `htm` together (`?` means 0 or 1 appearance):

```
\.(s|x)?(htm)l?.*
```

And, I always check if it's still working in [regexstorm for .Net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%28s%7cx%29%3f%28htm%29l%3f.*&i=.html%0d%0a.htm%0d%0a.shtml%0d%0a.shtm%0d%0a.xhtml%0d%0a.html*%0d%0a.htmlSomethingElse%0d%0a.htm*%0d%0a.htmSomethingElse%0d%0a.shtml*%0d%0a.shtmlSomethingElse%0d%0a.shtm*%0d%0a.shtmSomethingElse%0d%0a.xhtml*%0d%0a.xhtmlSomethingElse)

That way, you may also get regular expressions for the other 2 ones and concat them all together in the end.

Comment: Allright, i can now see a bunch of ways to implement this. For instance, the filter with the .html files, can be done like Wiktor said: `(?i)\.[xs]?htm\w*$`. But i want it in `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. Is this the best way to have it case insensitive? Also, i find that `.shtm` and `.shtml` does not match.

Comment: @Kirtstarweb In other languages you set these _flags_ with /gmi at the end (global, multiline, case insensitive), in .net you can set them this way. `(?i)` should work in .net as well, I guess. And `[xs]` (character class) is essentially the same as `(x|s)`. Wiktor also replaced your `.*`(any char) with `\w` which mathes only word chars(abc...), so no white spaces, line breaks or numbers. Those are further steps to refine an expression.

Comment: I think i see it now, i'll consider choosing which expression suites it best. Thank you for your help.